# How can I apply multiple regex on the same string in a efficient manner?

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I've a C# string and I need to match multiple patterns and remove them if they are found.

I did this and it works:

```
                    sede.Address = Regex.Replace(sede.Address, @"^(?i)str\.*", "Strada");
                    sede.Address = Regex.Replace(sede.Address, @"^(?i)fraz\.*", "Frazione");
                    sede.Address = Regex.Replace(sede.Address, @"^[^vV]\.*\w{2}\s", "");

                    sede.Address = Regex.Replace(sede.Address, @"\w+\.\w*", "");
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Even if you could find a way to merge multiple regexes into one, having one regex per rule makes readability and maintenance much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another better way to do what you want is composing all the patterns, do some `Matches` to get the collection of all the matches, loop through this collection and find the exact pattern then perform the corresponding replacement:

```
Dictionary<string,string> subPatterns = new Dictionary<string,string>();
subPatterns[@"^(?i)str\.*"] = "Strada";
subPatterns[@"^(?i)fraz\.*"] = "Frazione";
subPatterns[@"^(?-i)[^vV]\.*\w{2}\s|\w+\.\w*"] = "";
//build the compositing pattern from sub patterns
string pattern = string.Join("|", subPatterns.Select(e=>e.Key));
//replace it
StringBuilder address = new StringBuilder();
int nextStart = 0;
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(sede.Address, pattern)){
  if(m.Success){
     address.Append(sede.Address.Substring(nextStart,m.Index));
     //find the replacement
     foreach(var pat in subPatterns){
       if(Regex.IsMatch(m.Value,pat.Key)){
         address.Append(pat.Value);
         break;
       }
     }
     nextStart = m.Index + m.Length;         
  }
}
sede.Address = address.ToString();
```

**NOTE**: The code above works of course better than your original code (because the matching is done only once in a loop through all the characters in your input). But it's applicable only when your replacements **are independent**, otherwise you have to keep the original code.

Comment: Dictionary loses precedence (ordering) which might be desirable.

Comment: @leppie as I said in the note, if all the replacements are independent, the replacing order doesn't matter. Anyway, we can add the `OrderBy` clause if it's necessary. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't equivalent to the original code, I think you lose everything in between the matches.

Answer (score 1):

The only simple improvement would be to compile the regexes and store them for reuse rather than making new ones every time.  Combining alternate patterns makes the code harder to read.  In most regex implementations, the regex `a|b` is not faster than applying `a` and applying `b`.  Yes, you do loop through twice but you do half the work at each character so to a first approximation it's a wash.  Of course if it's important there's no substitute for measuring with real-world data.